# Is possible to create strongly typed action link helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

My goal is pretty simple I want to create strongly typed ActionLink helper for concrete controller in ASP.NET MVC. But it just doesn't work; I thought I'm  on right way... Can you give me any advice?

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLinkFor<TController>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TController, ActionResult>> action)
{
    return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```

Usage is pretty simple (`<li>@(Html.ActionLinkFor<HelloController>(a => a.Index))</li>`), but I'm ending with error message:

> CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'Index' to non-delegate type 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<li>@(Html.ActionLinkFor<HelloController>(a => a.Index))</li>
```

Use

```
<li>@(Html.ActionLinkFor<HelloController>(a => a.Index()))</li>
```